# Product attribute description on the product page

Tags: magento2

Is there a built-in way for Magento 2 to show product attribute description on the product page?

I mean something like this site:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build-in functionality for attribute descriptions but you can try this small module which extends attribute functionality

https://github.com/dmatthew/magento2-attribute-description